# 301 redirect from non-www to www for nginx

Tags: redirection, nginx, www

I am using following code in my site to do permanent 301 redirect from non-www domain to www domain. My web server is nginx.

```
rewrite ^/([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?$2 permanent;
```

This is working fine only for one case where a user types `http://example.com` which is redirected to `http://www.example.com`

But when a user types for e.g. `http://example.com/portal.php` then it doesn't redirect to `http://www.example.com/portal.php`

How can I make sure that all my pages redirect to www domain?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you need a `/` in your regex filter. Perhaps try this instead: `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]` Another solution may be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www) as I'm not fond of Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done with a different server block, with no regex required.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;

  # Location blocks etc
}
```

You can add additional server blocks if you want to redirect https.